# Getting a node by matching another nodes name or exclude a node by matching another node

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I have the following XML

```
  <section>
            <object>
                <field name="First Source" />
                <tableSection 
                        propertyCount="1"
                        rowCount="1">
                    <tableProperty height="0"
                            width="570"
                            visible="true">
                        <property name="commit" />
                    </tableProperty>
                    <tableRow height="0"
                            width="0">
                        <tableCell value="Value First Source" />    
                    </tableRow>
                </tableSection>
            </object>
            <object>
                <field name="Another Source" />
                <tableSection 
                        propertyCount="1"
                        rowCount="1">
                    <tableProperty height="0"
                            width="570"
                            visible="true">
                        <property name="commit" />
                    </tableProperty>    
                    <tableRow height="0"
                            width="0">
                        <tableCell value="Invalid Value" />
                    </tableRow>
                </tableSection>
            </object>
        </section>
```

and have an xslt as follows

```
<xsl:template match="tableRow">
    <xsl:variable name="rowNodePosition">
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <tr allowDblCl="true"  valign="top"  height="50px">
        <td>
            <b>Row:</b>
            <xsl:value-of select="$rowNodePosition"/>
            <br/>
            <xsl:for-each select="tableCell" >

                <xsl:variable name="currPosition">
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                </xsl:variable>                 
                <xsl:if test="@value != ''">
                    <b>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../tableProperty[position() = $currPosition]/property/@name"/>: </b>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                    <br/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" height="15px"> </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

This will gets all the 'tablRow'. But I need to exclude the tableRows which have the field name='Another Source' ie if the object node has 'field' with the name "Another Source", then exclude the tableRow of node tableSection

[image: Node hierarchy]

Comment: You want to apply templates recursively.. Create a template that only match the objects you want and from there tell it to apply the templates to match the tableRows.. this way the tableRow template will not fire for the ones you do not want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wrote, you want to exclude each **tableRow** element, with
corresponding field name with particular value.

If you want exclude some element in XSLT, the general rule is to write an
**empty template** for this element.

The name of this element is **tableRow**, but to narrow down the matching,
you have to add the following predicate:

- Move 2 levels up (to the **object** level).
- Descend to the child **field** element.
- Descend to its **name** attribute.
- Check whether its content is *Another Source*.

So add:

```
<xsl:template match="tableRow[../../field/@name = 'Another Source']"/>
```

to your XSLT script, to achieve what you want.

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/ei5PwjS